# Dúvida sobre instruções que podem ser implementadas no Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Pergunta de prova de curso técnico de Linguagem de programação Java:

> Quais instruções podem ser usadas no Hibernate?
>
> a- JDBC
>
> b- JPA
>
> c- SQL
>
> d- JNDI

Comment: Pergunta muito mal-elaborada, por sinal.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando "instruções" como instruções de manipulação e persistência de dados a resposta correta é:

- C- SQL

Answer (score 1):

O Hibernate é um ORM (Object Relational Mapping), uma "[técnica de mapeamento objeto relacional que permite fazer uma relação dos objetos com os dados que os mesmos representam](http://www.devmedia.com.br/orm-object-relational-mapper/19056)".

Fazendo algumas pequenas pesquisas no google:
[JDBC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC) - "Classes e interfaces para enviar instruções SQL para bancos qualquer banco de dados relacional". - JDB é um conector de bancos, assim como o hibernate, mas com outras técnicas e implementações, permitindo executar comandos SQL. ([Andremoniy, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163670/jdbc-vs-hibernate)).

[JPA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) - "Uma API padrão da linguagem Java que descreve uma interface comum para frameworks de persistência de dados" - JPA refere apenas às especificações, equanto Hibernate é uma implementação das especificações ([Bowersox, 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881611/whats-the-difference-between-jpa-and-hibernate)).

[**SQL**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) - É a linguagem de pesquisa declarativa padrão para banco de dados relacional (base de dados relacional) - SQL são os comandos do banco em sí. É o que é executado, seja explicitamente por comando ou "por baixo dos panos" por ORM. Assim, **essa é sua resposta**.

[JNDI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNDI) - "Uma API para acesso a serviços de diretórios. Ela permite que aplicações cliente descubram e obtenham dados ou objetos através de um nome" - Assim como o JDBC, o JDNI permite conectar à bancos e executar comandos SQL. ([jpkrohling, 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303671/configure-hibernate-to-connect-to-database-via-jndi-datasource)).

Sempre que possível, faça o dever de casa!

Answer (score 0):

HQL é o mecanismo no Hibernate para definir instruções do tipo SQL. No entanto, não acho correto dizer que o SQL pode ser lido pelo Hibernate e sim o HQL.